# How to be notified when a Feature geometry is changed?

Tags: openlayers-3

The documentation for ol.Feature [OL3 API](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.Feature.html) states that it fires a 'change:geometry' event.  The documentation does not specify when this event is fired.

The following [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zeyh3mvj/) has an example of moving vector features using an ol.interaction.Translate to move the features.  While a feature is being moved, a 'change' event is fired, but never a 'change:geometry' event.

What is the correct way to be informed that a Features geometry has been updated?

Code:

```
var select = new ol.interaction.Select();

select.on('select', (event) => {
  event.selected.forEach((selectedFeature) => {
      selectedFeature.on('change', (event) => {console.log('change', event)})
      selectedFeature.on('change:geometry', (event) => {console.log('change:geometry', event)})
  })
})

var translate = new ol.interaction.Translate({
  features: select.getFeatures()
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `change:geometry` event occurs at the level of the feature if you change the geometry object, i.e. if you did: `feature.setGeometry(aNewGeomObj)`, `feature.setGeometry(null)`, etc.

What you're looking for is listening the `change` event of the geometry object itself.  You can do this like this:

```
var geometry = feature.getGeometry();
geometry.on('change', function(evt) {
  console.log(evt)
}, this);
```

You should be able to do what you want from there.

Comment: It is a shame you cannot get the same information that you get from a 'propertychange' event where it provides the old value along with the changed object.  As a follow up, what does the fires "change:geometry" mean on the OpenLayers API pages?

Comment: See the first paragraph of the answer.